# What does tcpi_rcv_mss mean?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

As we known, MSS is Maximum Segment Size of TCP data.

In Ipv4, MSS is 1460 in general, and in Ipv6, MSS is 1440 in general.

But the strange thing is: there are two types of MSS in struct tcp_info, which is `tcpi_snd_mss` and `tcpi_rcv_mss`.

I did a simple experiment, connect `www.stackoverflow.com` and output these two values.

```c
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    assert(fd >= 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("151.101.193.69");

    int rc = connect(fd, (void*)&server, sizeof(server));
    assert(rc >= 0);

    struct tcp_info info;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(info);
    rc = getsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_INFO, (void*)&info, &len);
    assert(rc >= 0);


    printf("%u\n", info.tcpi_snd_mss);
    printf("%u\n", info.tcpi_rcv_mss);
    return 0;
}
```

```sh
$ ./a.out
1440
536
```

The `tcpi_rcv_mss` is 536!!

But according to `tcpdump`, the MSS should be 1440(my MSS is 1460, stackoverflow'MSS is 1440).

```sh
$ sudo tcpdump -n host 151.101.193.69
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:39:52.690772 IP 10.101.25.77.14947 > 151.101.193.69.80: Flags [S], seq 548910783, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3459919655 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
18:39:52.797959 IP 151.101.193.69.80 > 10.101.25.77.14947: Flags [S.], seq 577830562, ack 548910784, win 28800, options [mss 1440,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 9], length 0
18:39:52.798000 IP 10.101.25.77.14947 > 151.101.193.69.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 115, length 0
18:39:52.798333 IP 10.101.25.77.14947 > 151.101.193.69.80: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 115, length 0
18:39:53.160527 IP 10.101.25.77.14947 > 151.101.193.69.80: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 115, length 0
18:39:53.241597 IP 151.101.193.69.80 > 10.101.25.77.14947: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 57, length 0
18:39:53.241657 IP 10.101.25.77.14947 > 151.101.193.69.80: Flags [.], ack 2, win 115, length 0
```

So i have two questions:

1. What does `tcpi_rcv_mss` mean?
2. Why is `tcpi_rcv_mss` 536 in my experiment?

Comment: The sendind path isn't necessarily the same as the receiving path, and a study decades ago showed that in practice they are different something like 40% of the time.

Comment: According to rfc879: _The default TCP Maximum Segment Size is 536_.
At least Linux seems to use that value sometimes for initial RCV_MSS value.

Answer (score 0):

Receive MSS is the maximum segment size you announce to the other peer you can accept, and Transmit MSS is the value announced by your peer and marks the maximum segment size you can send to it.  Of course, there are two, yours doesn't have to be equal to your partner's.